# Archer C7 AC1750 Bridge Mode

Tags: wireless-router, dhcp, bridge

I have an Archer C7 AC1750 wireless router which is great but I can't enable bridge mode through my modem, so I need the Archer's DHCP service to be disabled and pass the DHCP from my modem through a LAN cable (not wireless). How can I do that?

Comment: You should get together with the author of http://superuser.com/questions/1050636/using-a-d-link-adsl-router-as-a-modem#comment1474068_1050636, since you both seem to have the same issue.  *"... I can't enable bridge mode through my modem"* -- Are you 100% sure, because that would be unusual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Archer C7 makes it easy to disable the DHCP server, but there's no way to to make the WAN port act like one of the LAN ports (that is, switch off all firewall/router/NAT gateway features, making it just a bridge). So you'll have to disable the C7's DHCP service, set its LAN port to have an IP address on the NAT private IP subnet that your upstream NAT gateway is providing (what you're calling your "modem" appears to have home gateway features; it's not "just" a modem), and connect a LAN port from your C7 to your "modem".

Comment: *"To make the WAN port act like one of the LAN ports"* usually requires an explicit feature/capability (i.e. turn a wireless router into a WAP).  Disabling NAT would probably not be sufficient.  E.G. you would also want to disable the firewall.

Comment: Doesn't mean I have to replace the Archer C7 firmware with custom one like OpenWrt ?

Comment: @Nabeel No, you just have to do what I suggested: Disable the C7's DHCP server, configure the C7's LAN interface to have an IP address on the subnet your "modem" creates, and connect the Ethernet from the modem to one of the C7's LAN ports instead of the C7's WAN port (leave the C7's WAN port empty).

Comment: @sawdust That's fair feedback. I was thinking of devices that fully switch between bridge mode and NAT mode, but you're right, there are plenty of devices (the C7 included) that have an IP router/firewall mode in between full-blown NAT and simple bridging, so turning off NAT is not the same thing as enabling simple WAN <-> LAN bridging. I've edited my Answer to fix that mistake.

Comment: @Spiff how to configure the lan port to have an IP?

Comment: @Spiff THANK YOU, you are a semi-god. This worked on Arched D7 too.